# AutoComplete in ipython with pandas Seems to be broken

Tags: python, pandas, autocomplete, ipython

I have a pandas dataframe named **frame**

I want to invoke the `frame[SomeCoulmnname].value_counts()` method

The issue is that ipython doesnt autocomplete even after i type **v** after the **.**
In fact it doesnt even return any suggestions.

But if i simply type **Series**. and press the tab it return me the possible methods that i am looking for.

My question is why is iPython behaving like this?The same work with PyCharm though!

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't specific to pandas.

IPython cannot know/guess the type of the object returned by running `frame[SomeCoulmnname]` without actually running it. Since it also cannot assume running it is safe/fast/etc, it doesn't run it.

Since it doesn't know the type of the object, it can't suggest completions for it.

`Series.<TAB>` works because no guessing is required. IPython knows that `Series` is a type, hence it can resolve its members.

A solution would be to assign the temporary value to a variable:

```
s = frame[SomeCoulmnname]
s.v<TAB>
```

Comment: ok ..so you are suggesting that i will have to store the result of  `frame[somecolumnname]` to another variable each time??i tried it and its working ...but it feels so heavy on me since i am a learner :)

Comment: I am marking this answer as correct...since it is working :) ..Also i will be eager to listen for other possible solutions on this ...Thanks shx2 :)

Comment: If your column name is a valid Python identifier, you can access it like `frame.SomeColumnname.value_counts()`, and this way IPython will offer tab completions for it.