# Problem with autocompletion with Pandas in Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am having a problem [similar to this user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30016101/1379826): when calling autocomplete on `df.col.`, I get no autocompletion even after evaluating a cell containing only `df.col`. For instance, I'd like to see `df.col.str.matc` to autocomplete to `df.col.str.match`. What can I do to solve this?

Take as example the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Alex in FL','ten'],['Bob in FLORIDA','five'],['Will in GA','three']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])

#Dataframe:
    Name             Age
0   Alex in FL       ten
1   Bob in FLORIDA   five
2   Will in GA       three

#Command that should autocomplete (but does not):
df.Name.str.matc [+TAB]
```

I do not want to try [hinterland](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/hinterland/README.html) since I only want autocomplete upon pressing tab.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `df.columns.str.match` is the thing you are looking for. `df.col. +tab` will not give anything since there is nothing like `df.col.` (col is not an attribute of dataframe).

Comment: @vb_rises to clarify, `col` is one of the columns in the `df`, so that `df.col` is a series. But anyways, `df.columns.str.matc + tab` still does not autocomplete. the problem remains

Comment: if `col` contains string values like 'abc', 'def' or in other words, it's type is object, then `df.col.str.mat + tab` will work. But if `col` has integer or float values (type is int or float), then `df.col.str.mat + tab` will not autocomplete. You can convert it to `x = df.col.astype('str')` and then try `x.str.mat + tab`, it should work.

Comment: @vb_rises thanks. I'll edit my question to clarify these points, but my dataframe falls on your first example, but it doesn't work in any case.

Comment: your updated example perfectly works fine with me. My pandas version is `0.19.2`. check your version. And I hope that you are running `df.Name.st.mat` + TAB in a NEW CELL after initializing df.

Comment: I'm running pandas `0.25.0`. I am running things properly, and bear in mind that I can autocomplete `df.Nam` to `df.Name`, but not `df.Name.str.mat`.

Comment: can you tell which ipython version you have using `ipython --version` on linux terminal. Check [this](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2435), other people has this issue with some versions and usin `c.Completer.use_jedi = False` in the configuration file solves the issue More information is also on [this](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html) page to set config file.

Comment: @vb_rises thanks for your help. I'm running `ipython 7.8.0`. Indeed, setting that as False solved the problem! Would you please create an answer so that I can give you the credit for helping me solve? I have ran `ipython profile create`, and then edited the file `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` to have: ` c = get_config()` and `c.Completer.use_jedi = False`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading [this](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2435), it seems that this problem is faced by other people and with specific version of ipython. The solution is also given on that link.

It is like this:

Run below command from the terminal:

```
ipython profile create
```

It will create a default profile at `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`

Now edit this `ipython_config.py` and add the below lines and it will solve the issue.

```
c = get_config()
c.Completer.use_jedi = False
```

Reference:

1. https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2435
2. https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html